# Karma/Jasmine: Unable to test a service method being called inside a component in Angular 4

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, karma-jasmine

I am new to karma/jasmine and trying to test a code where a component method calls a service method and expects a value in return.

**Component**
Here is a small component which I created.
**isLoginRequired()** gets called within **ngOnInit()** which further executes **this.service.checkAuthentication()**.

```
export class AppComponent implements OnInit {
  public title = 'app';
  public showLoginBtn = true;

  constructor(private service: CustomService) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    localStorage.setItem('key', '12345');
    this.title = 'name changed';
    this.isLoginRequired();
  }

  isLoginRequired() {
    this.showLoginBtn = this.service.checkAuthentication();
  }
}
```

**Service**
This is the custom service inside which the method **checkAuthentication()** resides.

```
@Injectable()
export class CustomService {

  constructor() { }

  checkAuthentication(): boolean {
    return !!localStorage.getItem('key');
  }
}
```

**Specs**
This is the spec file where I am writing the unit test cases. Please refer to **test case #4**.

```
describe('App component testing', () => {

  let component: AppComponent;
  let service: CustomService;
  let fixture;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        CustomPipe,
        CustomDirective
      ],
      providers: [
        CustomService
      ]
    }).compileComponents();
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AppComponent);
    component = fixture.debugElement.componentInstance;
    service = TestBed.get(CustomService);
  });

  // test case #1
  it('component creation', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  // test case #2
  it('has title "app"', () => {
    expect(component.title).toBe('app');
  });

  // test case #3
  it('isLoginRequired is triggered', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'isLoginRequired');
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.isLoginRequired).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });

  // test case #4
  it('service.checkAuthentication is triggered', () => {
    spyOn(component, 'isLoginRequired');
    spyOn(service, 'checkAuthentication');
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(component.isLoginRequired).toBeTruthy();
    expect(service.checkAuthentication).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

**Errors**

```
Error: Expected spy checkAuthentication to have been called.
```

I really need help here.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're spying on isLoginRequired, effectively replacing this method of the component by a method that does nothing. So when you call it... it does nothing. Don't spy on the object you're testing. Spy on the **dependencies** of the object you're testing.

Comment: @JBNizet something like this?

    spyOn(service, 'checkAuthentication');
    component.ngOnInit();
    expect(service.checkAuthentication).toHaveBeenCalled();

Because this worked but I'm not sure if it's correct.

Comment: Yes, it's correct.

Answer (score 0):

Change `spyOn(component, 'isLoginRequired');` into `spyOn(component, 'isLoginRequired').and.callThrough();`

The default is to not execute the Methode.